# What does window.clientHeight specifies in mobile screens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a simple doubt that when we specify window.clientheight in JavaScript for mobile screens, does it tells the whole screen's height including navigation panel (shown in image) or it excludes that panel.
[image]

And if it includes that panel (as I'm guessing), how can I specify only screen's width excluding the panel.

Comment: Nothing, that property doesn't exist in `window`.

Comment: [`clientHeight`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) is an `Element` property. Did you mean [`innerHeight`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight)? What does the documentation reveal? What does the specification say (also linked in the docs)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your senerio, window.innerHeight is better option for you. I guess.

```js
console.log(window.innerHeight)
```

Comment: so what's the difference b/w innerHeight and clientHeight

Comment: @UtsavMeena The documentation explains the difference pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

clientHeight belongs to an element and window is not an element. So there is nothing for window.clientHeight.

```
window.clientHeight = undefined
```

read this, this may help you : https://javascript.info/size-and-scroll-window